# Can ServiceStack Profiler be used to profile MongoDB calls?

Tags: mongodb, profiling, servicestack

I see with the standard MiniProfiler, you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.MongoDb to profile MongoDB calls, but is it possible to do with the built in https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Mini Profiler Sql Profiling is limited to profiling an ADO.NET DB Connection. There's no profiling support for MongoDB.